# Custom customer attribute in sales email

Tags: magento2, order-email

I've got a custom customer attribute containing the customer ID from an external system that I can access via `$customer->getExternalId()`.

I want to put that ID in my order confirmation emails. How can I do that? I've tried `{{var order.getCustomer().getExternalId()}}`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?

Comment: @AndreasDaoutis No, sorry.